# Sufficient statistics and parametric bootstrapping

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, sufficient-statistics

Does the resampling step of the bootstrap method require to have the sample entirely, or a sufficient statistic suffices?

In general, the bootstrapping can be nonparametric or parametric. In the former case, we can simply keep the frequency of each distinct observation, and we have the empirical distribution to draw bootstrap samples from. In the latter case, the idea of only keeping a *sufficient statistic* seems interesting. Are there any pitfalls which should be avoided in this case?

Comment: I am struggling to understand the question posed in the last line. It literally asks "is a [sufficient] statistic really sufficient?" What kind of answers are you expecting to such a question? Do you seek an explanation of what a sufficient statistic is? Or have you changed the meaning of "sufficient" at the end so that it is now used in a conventional sense of "enough to get the job done correctly" rather than in the technical sense of a *sufficient* statistic?

Comment: @whuber The question raised in my mind because a sufficient statistic (in its _technical_ sense) is chosen according to on an _unknown parameter_ (namely $\theta$). If we are just evaluating the correctness of an MLE of $\theta$, doesn't summarizing the real sample by a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ destroy the accuracy information?

Comment: Perhaps you ought to say a few words concerning why you are bootstrapping and what you hope to accomplish with it. AFAIK this method is not used "evaluate the correctness" of an estimator (which could mean several different things). It is a technique for reducing bias and obtaining standard errors of estimates.

Comment: @whuber I wrote "correctness" but you should read "accuracy" :-). The bootstrapping is used to measure the _accuracy_ of an estimator---e.g. to determine the confidence interval of the mean ($\mu$) of a normal distribution (known variance $\sigma^2$) which is estimated by sample mean ($\bar{x}$). In this case, $\bar{x}$ is also a sufficient statistic for $\mu$. If we discard all the observations and keep $\bar{x}$ and draw bootstrap samples from $\hat{F} \sim N(\bar{x},\sigma^2)$, aren't we going a wrong way?

Comment: I don't understand what "going a wrong way" might mean: you have described a parametric bootstrap from an IID sample of a Normal distribution. Since *by definition* a sufficient statistic tells you everything you can possibly know about the parameter $\mu$ based on the data (given the distributional assumptions), what else is there to say? You seem to be asking why sufficient statistics do not have the property of sufficiency; it's hard to know how to respond to such a question.

Comment: @whuber OK. If we were certain about the _real_ distribution of the observations (i.e. being $N(?, \sigma^2)$), there would be no doubt about sufficient stats telling "everything...". But how can we be certain? BTW, I think you are answering my question. Could you please post an _answer_?

Comment: Although I am glad you see an answer emerging, I cannot possibly *post* an answer because I still don't understand the question!  Your last comment seems to change everything: now you appear to be asking something general about statistical estimation. Remember, a bootstrap estimate is just another estimate and its properties can be evaluated using the general principles governing all estimators. There will *always* be concerns about whether one's assumptions are appropriate, but I cannot tell whether that is the thrust of your questioning or not.

Comment: @whuber I think I have confused some topics with each other. The answer to my question should be: always  sufficient statistics can be used to estimate distribution parameter(s). The parametric distribution in the bootstrapping is no exception. However, the bootstrapping is usually applied to complex distributions and/or estimators. Therefore, while the idea is interesting at first, it may be impractical to apply.